# Add text to the first line of a file

Tags: python

I had a line of Python code that produced what I wanted. The code was:

```
os.system('cat {0}|egrep {1} > file.txt' .format(full,epoch))
```

and produced a file with the following contents:

```
3                321.000 53420.7046629965511    0.299                 0.00000
3                325.000 53420.7046629860714    0.270                 0.00000
3                329.000 53420.7046629846442    0.334                 0.00000
3                333.000 53420.7046629918374    0.280                 0.00000
```

I then just wanted to adjust the code so that is said "TEXT 1" at the top, so I tried the first thing that came into my head, and I changed the code to:

```
h = open('file.txt','w')
h.write('MODE 2\n')
os.system('cat {0}|egrep {1} > file.txt' .format(full,epoch))
```

When I do this, I get the output:

```
TEXT 1
   317.000 54519.6975201839344    0.627                 0.00000
3                321.000 54519.6975202038578    0.655                 0.00000
3                325.000 54519.6975201934045    0.608                 0.00000
3                329.000 54519.6975201919911    0.612                 0.00000
```

i.e. the first line after "TEXT 1" is not right, and is missing the first "3". Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong, and possibly a better way to do this simple task.

Thank you.

Comment: Check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4454298/prepend-a-line-to-an-existing-file-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You open a file handle with python, write to it, but Python leaves it to the OS to do the flushing, etc. - by design, if want something to be written to file *before* something else gets written, you'll need to [`flush`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.flush) it manually (in fact, you'll need to `flush` *and* `fsync`).

Another note: The `> file.txt` creates a new file, while you might want to *append* - which would be written as `>> file.txt`. In short: your code might be more indeterministic as you think.

Another way to do it, since you are already on the shell level is to use the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-os-system) module:

```
from subprocess import call

sts = call("echo 'TEXT 1' > file.txt", shell=True)
sts = call("cat {0}|egrep {1} >> file.txt".format(full,epoch), shell=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can call grep your way, or you can use subprocess.call(), which is my preferred method.

#### Method 1: use os.system()

```
os.system('echo TEXT 1 >file.txt; egrep {1} {0} >> file.txt'.format(full, epoch))
```

This method will prepend *TEXT 1* before invoking `egrep`. Note that you don't need `cat`.

#### Method 2: use subprocess.call()

```
with open('out.txt', 'wb') as output_file:
    output_file.write('TEXT 1\n')
    output_file.flush()
    subprocess.call(['egrep', epoch, full], stdout=output_file)
```

This is my preferred method for several reasons: you have more control over the output file such as the ability to handle exception in case open failed.