# Write date to the top of a CSVFile python

Tags: python, csv, python-datetime

I have this code:

```
def write_csv(path, inputdata):
    with open(path, 'w', errors='ignore', newline='') as newfile:
        writer = csv.writer(newfile, dialect='excel')
        writer.writerows(inputdata)
```

I would like to write the date at the top of the CSV file. I tried to include

```
writer.writerow(datetime.date.today())
```

This as expected really returned `_csv.Error: iterable expected, not datetime.date`
How else could I do it? Include it as the fieldnames and write as a `DictWriter`? I'm not confident that would work though.

Comment: Try to convert the date object to string first using strftime(): https://thispointer.com/python-how-to-convert-datetime-object-to-string-using-datetime-strftime/

Comment: This writes it to the CSV in this form:
`2,7,-,M,a,y,-,2,0,2,0`. This is clearly not very useful as I need it as `27 May 2020`

Comment: It looks like you've already got some answers. Question, though: Is the CSV file blank to begin? Or does it contain data already? To add the date in after data is present, there is a clever answer by Hai Vu at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28162358/append-a-header-for-csv-file

Comment: @patmcb file gets truncated at the start. This would work however I’m using this for lots of CSVs so easier to just writerow it does matter where it happens really

Answer (score 1):

`writerow` takes an iterable.  If you have only one string, you have to wrap it in `[]` or `writerow` will iterate over single characters in the iterable string instead of iterating over objects in an iterable list.

```
import csv
import datetime

with open('test.csv', 'w', newline='') as newfile:
        writer = csv.writer(newfile)
        writer.writerow([f'{datetime.date.today():%d-%B-%Y}'])
```

Output:

```
27-May-2020
```

Comment: Returns: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'keys'`, using your exact line of code copied into my function. I also defined `datetime.date.today` as `todays_date` and `writer.writerow([todays_date])`, this returned the same error.

Comment: @PythonIsBae Code above works in Python 3.6.  Did you try the *exact* code above? I can't fix your code if I can't see it, but my crystal ball says you switched to a `csv.DictWriter`, because `.writerow()` would expect a dictionary which has a `.keys()` method.