# Compact way of pre-pending mutiple text files in python

Tags: python, text, prepend

a bit of a silly question. I am trying to insert (prepend) multiple text files (`apple`, `banana`, `pear`) into a main text file (`fruitsalad.txt`).
How do a make this more concise? (PS there is more fruit than what I am showing!)

```
input01 = path_include + 'apple.txt'
input02 = path_include + 'banana.txt'
input03 = path_include + 'pear.txt'

prepend01 = open(input01,'r').read()
prepend02 = open(input02,'r').read()
prepend03 = open(input03,'r').read()

open(fruitsalad_filepath, 'r+').write(prepend01+prepend02+prepend03 + open(fruitsalad_filepath).read())
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4454298/prepend-a-line-to-an-existing-file-in-python#4454522 for why there's no fundamentally easier way to achieve this.
Also consider the comment below that question that suggests using a temporary file in order not to risk data loss on crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have some list

```
fruit = ['apple.txt', 'banana.txt', 'pear.txt']
```

you can open the target file, then write the contents of each fruit file across one at a time

```
with open(fruitsalad_filepath, 'w+') as salad:
    for item in fruit:
        with open(path_include+item) as f:
            salad.write(f.read())
```

Doing it this way means you don't have to save the text in intermediate variables, which could eat up a lot of memory.  Also, you should read up on the use of context managers in python (the `with ... as ... :` statements)

Comment: I've actually realised that my question was incomplete, leading to an inaccurate answer.
At the time of appending, the file `salad` already contains data that should not be overwritten, but pre-prended by the content of the list `fruit`

Comment: @Andreuccio Then you need to read that data into memory before the loop I wrote, then write it at the end of the file after the loop.  There isn't a way to write to the beginning of a file without writing over existing information.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `glob` (https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) to include everything in a `for` loop. Then you could put all your input's content in a string. Also, I would use `with` so that you don't have to worry about file handlers.

```
import glob

prepend_text = ""

for input in glob.glob("%s*.txt" % (path_include)):
   with open(input, 'r') as f:
      prepend_text += f.read()

with open(fruitsalad_filepath, 'r') as f:
   prepend_text += f.read()

with open(fruitsalad_filepath, 'w') as f:
   f.write(prepend_text)
```

Note that this code assumes that `fruitsalad_filepath` is NOT in `path_include`. If it is, then you'll have to add some checks (and remove the last read).

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like this:

```
import codecs
# for example you prepared list of .txt files in folder
# all_files - list of all file names
all_files = [] 
# content from all files
salad_content = ''

for file_name in all_files:
    # open each file and read content
    with codecs.open(file_name, encoding='utf-8') as f:
        salad_content += f.read()

# write prepared content from all files to final file
with codecs.open(fruitsalad_filepath, 'w', 'utf-8') as f:
    f.write(salad_content)
```

For finding `.txt` files in the folder you can use [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964681/find-all-files-in-directory-with-extension-txt-in-python).

Answer (score 0):

While, instead of opening every files, try to use the offical libraray [fileinput](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html), and then you can open multi files together in iterator way, as you can see the function:

> fileinput.input([files[, inplace[, backup[, bufsize[, mode[, openhook]]]]]])

Comment: there seems to be an issue with the syntax of your one-liner